# Restrict some charcters in special characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have tried regular expression that considers only statements that have zero or more occurances of "%" and "&"  and returns false if "@" or "$" is present. :

```
^((%&)*(?!@).)*$
```

What I need is a regular expression that validates only those strings that must have 2 or more special characters from the set (%&) and return false if any other special character is present.

Comment: `string.match(/^(?!.*[@$])/)` .........

Comment: .* would mean any other charcters I need to exclude only some of the special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?=(?:.*[%&]){2,})(?!.*[@$])^.*$
```

Positive lookahead to make sure `%` or `&` occur at least 2 times

Negative lookahead to make sure `@` and `$` don't occur at all

**Edit**

Now makes sure to match entire string (`^`, `$`)

Check it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/aohYPa/2)

Comment: I tried this ,Sorry but it does not work for this combination "wsd%FDFuu%@%%"

Comment: Thanks a lot worked!! Can u break the explanation into more detail.